# TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object (mongoose error)

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, typeerror

I'm using these versions: `"mongodb": "^3.6.3", "mongoose": "^5.10.18"` and I'm having an issue where sometimes when I do a mongo SomeModel.create() in a cron job, it fails because of this error:

`TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object` and it fails on the node_modules/mongoose line in the screenshot below. This used to work completely fine and one day it just started happening without me changing the package versions or any other related code.

I see that I could revert back to a mongoose version like 3.9 that doesn't include the code in this screenshot but it still confuses me how this started to be flaky one day whereas it used to work perfectly fine on the same versions.

Here is roughly how I write my .create()

```
          await Repayment.create({
            userId: user._id,
            isAutopay: true
          });
```

Any ideas on how I can fix? Thanks!

[screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VhXJ.png)

Comment: Node version? Did you overwrite `String` by accident somewhere? Also, we don't post screenshots of errors here. It should be pasted as text

Comment: Nope I didn't. And also it works on my cron job in my staging server but not in my prod server (although there was a period of 2 days where it wasn't working on my staging server...i didn't change anything and it resolved itself). Using heroku to host btw @Konrad